# Bootstrap carousel, modified to show multiple items. Not properly working Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I spend quite some time in finding modifications of the bootstrap carousel, which is able to show multiple items in one view. Instead of one item. However, all the examples I have found have some minor issues. The best example I found is this one: 
http://codepen.io/Jazzzper86/pen/BKVzNg.

It works fine in Chrome but, but not in Firefox and internet explorer. Does anyone know an example of a multiple item bootstrap carousel that does work properly in all browsers? And if not, what type of carousel would be a good alternative? Thanks!

the javascript which is used:

```
// Instantiate the Bootstrap carousel
$('.multi-item-carousel').carousel({
  interval: false
});

// for every slide in carousel, copy the next slide's item in the slide.
// Do the same for the next, next item.
$('.multi-item-carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
    next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  } else {
    $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
  }
});
```

The CSS (less) which is used:

```
.multi-item-carousel{
  .carousel-inner{
    > .item{
      transition: 500ms ease-in-out left;
    }
    .active{
      &.left{
        left:-33%;
      }
      &.right{
        left:33%;
      }
    }
    .next{
      left: 33%;
    }
    .prev{
      left: -33%;
    }
    @media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
      > .item{
        // use your favourite prefixer here
        transition: 500ms ease-in-out all;
        backface-visibility: visible;
        transform: none!important;
      }
    }
  }
  .carouse-control{
    &.left, &.right{
      background-image: none;
    }
  }
}

// non-related styling:
body{
  background: #333;
  color: #ddd;
}
h1{
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.25em;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Use Bootstrap's carousel to show multiple items per slide.</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel slide multi-item-carousel" id="theCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/f44336/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/e91e63/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/9c27b0/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/673ab7/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/4caf50/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4"><a href="#1"><img src="http://placehold.it/300/8bc34a/000000" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#theCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/zDQkr](https://bootsni)

run this code snippet on full width window

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var itemsMainDiv = ('.MultiCarousel');
    var itemsDiv = ('.MultiCarousel-inner');
    var itemWidth = "";

    $('.leftLst, .rightLst').click(function () {
        var condition = $(this).hasClass("leftLst");
        if (condition)
            click(0, this);
        else
            click(1, this)
    });

    ResCarouselSize();




    $(window).resize(function () {
        ResCarouselSize();
    });

    //this function define the size of the items
    function ResCarouselSize() {
        var incno = 0;
        var dataItems = ("data-items");
        var itemClass = ('.item');
        var id = 0;
        var btnParentSb = '';
        var itemsSplit = '';
        var sampwidth = $(itemsMainDiv).width();
        var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
        $(itemsDiv).each(function () {
            id = id + 1;
            var itemNumbers = $(this).find(itemClass).length;
            btnParentSb = $(this).parent().attr(dataItems);
            itemsSplit = btnParentSb.split(',');
            $(this).parent().attr("id", "MultiCarousel" + id);


            if (bodyWidth >= 1200) {
                incno = itemsSplit[3];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else if (bodyWidth >= 992) {
                incno = itemsSplit[2];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else if (bodyWidth >= 768) {
                incno = itemsSplit[1];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else {
                incno = itemsSplit[0];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            $(this).css({ 'transform': 'translateX(0px)', 'width': itemWidth * itemNumbers });
            $(this).find(itemClass).each(function () {
                $(this).outerWidth(itemWidth);
            });

            $(".leftLst").addClass("over");
            $(".rightLst").removeClass("over");

        });
    }


    //this function used to move the items
    function ResCarousel(e, el, s) {
        var leftBtn = ('.leftLst');
        var rightBtn = ('.rightLst');
        var translateXval = '';
        var divStyle = $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform');
        var values = divStyle.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
        var xds = Math.abs(values[4]);
        if (e == 0) {
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) - parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval <= itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = 0;
                $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        else if (e == 1) {
            var itemsCondition = $(el).find(itemsDiv).width() - $(el).width();
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) + parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval >= itemsCondition - itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = itemsCondition;
                $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform', 'translateX(' + -translateXval + 'px)');
    }

    //It is used to get some elements from btn
    function click(ell, ee) {
        var Parent = "#" + $(ee).parent().attr("id");
        var slide = $(Parent).attr("data-slide");
        ResCarousel(ell, Parent, slide);
    }

});
```

```css
.MultiCarousel { float: left; overflow: hidden; padding: 15px; width: 100%; position:relative; }
    .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner { transition: 1s ease all; float: left; }
        .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item {width: 190px; float: left;}
        .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item > div { text-align: center; padding:10px; margin:10px; background:#f1f1f1; color:#666;}
    .MultiCarousel .leftLst, .MultiCarousel .rightLst { position:absolute; border-radius:50%;top:calc(50% - 20px); }
    .MultiCarousel .leftLst { left:0; }
    .MultiCarousel .rightLst { right:0; }
    
        .MultiCarousel .leftLst.over, .MultiCarousel .rightLst.over { pointer-events: none; background:#ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="MultiCarousel" data-items="1,3,5,6" data-slide="1" id="MultiCarousel"  data-interval="1000">
            <div class="MultiCarousel-inner">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary leftLst">PREV</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary rightLst">NEXT</button>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

pp.com/snippets/zDQkr